# How to differentiate between text file and json file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Hi i have a situation where i want to differentiate between `plain text file` and `json file`   upon file read

right now i'm unable to differentiate between `plain text content` and `json content`

**here is what i'm doing:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function checkforJson(string){
     return typeof string === 'object';
}


var fileLocation = path.join(__dirname, 'watchfolder/');

fs.readFile(fileLocation, (eventType, filename) => { 
    var filecontent = fs.readFileSync(fileLocation+""+filename);
    filecontent = filecontent.toString();

   if(checkforJson(filecontent)){
       // json file
    }else{
      // plain text file
    }
});
```

**Most welcomed:** best way to solve this

**Question:**  but the above check is not working for some reason for what is best way to do this?

Comment: How about you check for the file extension?

Comment: Uh, I may be missing something but...try to parse it as JSON. If it doesn't work, then it's not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There's not difference between them because JSON is a string, and JSON file is text file.

Considering that the difference between JSON file and *the rest of text files* in this case is that it has .json extension, it could be:

```
if (/\.json$/i.test(filename)) {
  const data = JSON.parse(filecontent);
} else {
  // plain text file
}
```

If files should be differentiated by content then `JSON.parse` should be tried on them:

```
try {
  const data = JSON.parse(filecontent);
} catch (err) {
  // plain text file
}
```

In the second case it's impossible to tell whether this is not JSON or JSON that has formatting problems.

Comment: based on the content how can i go about that , rather then checking `file extension` , please help me with that

Comment: Please, update the question with this requirement as this provides different context to the question. Then you will need to use `try { data = JSON.parse(filecontent) } catch (err) { // plain text file }`, as another answer already suggested. Notice that this doesn't mean this is not JSON. This means that this is not *valid* JSON. Bad JSON will be considered text file.

Comment: as you **Suggested** Notice that this doesn't mean this is not JSON. This means that this is not valid JSON. Bad JSON will be considered text file,

**this is what the actual problem is? how can i go about solving this?**

Comment: Yes, this is what the problem is. You can solve it by storing your data wisely, so you know whether it's JSON or not. E.g. a file that contains `1`. Is it JSON or not? It will be parsed as valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a `try-catch` block with `JSON.parse`?

```
function checkforJson(json) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(json);
    }
    catch (e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add a regex like so:

```
var JSONorTXT = function(fileToCheck)
    let isJSON = regex.test(/.*$\.json/)
    if (isJSON === true) {
        var filetype = "json"            
        return filetype
    }
    else {
        var filetype = "txt"
        return filetype
   }
```

I'm not entirely sure, but this should work.

Comment: oh i see the bracket error. i'm working on python so i forgot about it. and this should work still, just a different approach